# Как оперировать названиями словарей вложенных в список?

Tags: python, list, словари

Домашние животные: создайте несколько словарей, имена которых представляют клички домашних животных. В каждом словаре сохраните информацию о виде животного и имени владельца. Сохраните словари в списке с именем pets. Переберите элементы списка. В процессе перебора выведите всю имеющуюся информацию о каждом животном.

Перебрать ключи и их значения было просто. Но по заданию необходимо вывести всю информацию о питомце. Если бы это были словари в словаре, то это не составило бы труда.

```
    pets = []
    murca = {'cat': 'alex'}
    barbos = {'dog': 'vitalik'}
    pirate = {'bird': 'kate'}
    pets.append(murca)
    pets.append(barbos)
    pets.append(pirate)
    for pet in pets:
        for kind, owner in pet.items():
            print(f"{owner.title()}'s {kind}.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с перебором globals, является довольно надёжным, однако переменная должна существовать, то есть нельзя применять `del murca` перед основным циклом, либо присваивать новое значение `murca=666`

```
def getname(dct):
    for key,val in globals().items():
        if val==dct:
            return key

for pet in pets:
    print(getname(pet),pet)
'''
murca {'cat': 'alex'}
barbos {'dog': 'vitalik'}
pirate {'bird': 'kate'}
'''
```

То есть в питоне имеется функция globals, которая возвращает словарь всех существующих переменных. Данный метод основан на переборе этого словаря, но ищётся значение, чтобы вернуть его ключ, иначе говоря ищется название переменной списка по значению списка.

```
print(globals())
#{__......}
my_variable=666
print(globals())
#{__..., 'my_variable':666}
print( globals()['my_variable'])
#666
```

Так же есть вариант с чтением исполняемого файла, если переменные заданы жёстко,- имеет ключевой недостаток- малопригоден и трудноисполним. И самый надёжный но не реализуемый моими силами это как-нить прикрутить модуль traceback.

Comment: Видимо, в условии все же не подразумевалось использование имен питомцев. Данное решение пока слишком сложно для меня.

Comment: @AliaksandrChachanets добавил объяснений

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что вы не до конца понимаете тип данных словарь. Словарь содержит пару `ключ:значение`. Так вот, у всех питомцев могут быть одинаковые ключи, по которым осуществляется доступ к значениям. То есть словари на мой взгляд должны быть примерно такими

```py
murca = {"name": "murca", "owner":"Alex", "type":"cat"} 
barbos = {"name": "barbos", "owner":"Vitalik", "type":"dog"}
```

Каждый словарь содержит значения о имени, владельце и типе животного. Ключи, как видите все одинаковые. Но один и тот же словарь не может содержать одинаковые ключи, они уникальны.

Следовательно перебор значений будет осуществляться так:

```py
for item in pets:
  print(f'{item["owner"]} has a {item["type"]} named {item["name"]}')
```

Вывод будет таким:

```
Alex has a cat named murca
Vitalik has a dog named barbos
```

Чтобы исключить ошибки в создании питомцев, я бы создал общую функцию, которая бы возвращала словарь и подразумевала наличие одинаковых ключей. То есть одним движением вы избавитесь от опечаток в ключах.

```py
# Поскольку имя type зарезервировано в python я использую нижнее 
# подчеркивание в конце, чтобы избежать конфликтов в именах
def create_pet(name, owner, type_):
  return {"name":name, "owner":owner, "type":type_}
```

И добавлять питомцев становится проще и понятней:

```py
pets = []
pets.append(create_pet(name="Murca", owner="Alex", type_="cat"))
# или еще проще
pets.append(create_pet("Barbos", "Vitalik", "dog"))
# а вот так вы получите ошибку и сразу поймете, что что-то не так
pets.append(create_pet("IIIapuk"))

# out
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# TypeError: create_pet() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'owner' and 'type_'
```

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже сейчас учусь по данной книге.
Я решил данное задание следующим образом:

```
pet_1={'name':'barsik','animal':'cat','owner':'kostya'}
pet_2={'name':'larisa','animal':'rat','owner':'inna'}
pet_3={'name':'bobik','animal':'dog','owner':'kolya'}

pets=[pet_1,pet_2,pet_3]
for pet in pets:
    print(f"\nNew pet:")
    for k,v in pet.items():
        print(f"{k}:{v}")
```

Получилось следующее:

```
New pet:
name:barsik
animal:cat
owner:kostya

New pet:
name:larisa
animal:rat
owner:inna

New pet:
name:bobik
animal:dog
owner:kolya
```

Стиль решения основам на примерах, приведенных в ранее изученных главах книги.